# Transform CURL to Http facade Laravel

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
$httpParams = [
    'textData'  =>  $content,
    'xmlFile'   =>  new \CurlFile($params['file']->getPathName())
];
$curlHandle = curl_init('http://url.com');
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $httpParams);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curlResponse = curl_exec($curlHandle);
curl_close($curlHandle);
dump($curlResponse);die();
```

I have the response in `$curlResponse` with status = 200

But when I tried with Http from Laravel:

```
$http = Http::asForm();
$httpParams = [
    'textData'  =>  $content,
    'xmlFile'   =>  new \CurlFile($params['file']->getPathName())
];
$response = $http->send('post', 'http://url.com', $httpParams)->body();
dump($response);
```

Response is empty: `""`. The status is 200. Why do I have an empty response when using Http facade?

Comment: Why not use it like the examples in the docs either: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#multi-part-requests or https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#sending-a-raw-request-body, and an empty response is fine, it entirely depends on what the server your sending it to has been programmed to respond with

Answer (score 0):

You can write reusable method  inside separate class

```
public function apiCall($url, $method = "get",$data=[])
{
   $htppCall = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
     ])->{$method}($url,$data);
      
    if ($htppCall->status() == 401) {
        //error handling
    }


        return $htppCall->object();
}
```

Then call like this

```
$httpParams = [
    'textData'  =>  $content,
    'xmlFile'   =>  new \CurlFile($params['file']->getPathName())
];
$response=$this->apiCall($url,'post',$httpParams);

dd($response);
```

Import right facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
```

checking what status code you got

```
$htppCall->status()
```

to get data as object

```
$htppCall->object()
```

To get data as array

```
$htppCall->json()
```

To check client errors

```
$htppCall->clientError()
```

to check server errors

```
$htppCall->serverError()
```

To Get the body of the response.

```
 $htppCall->body()
```

If any issues let me know in comment

Comment: thank you but I have an issue, so using Http facade, the api return in body : `This is NOT a multipart/form-data`, with `Curl` I don't have the message :(

Comment: can you show what exactly the output of that request

Comment: `<Error message="This is NOT a multipart/form-data" code="110"/>`

Comment: try once removing headers as json

Comment: difficult to guess than debugging . :)

Comment: ya but i cant guess .debugging is best way .try once in postman and verify what headers it passes

Comment: In postman is working then I add as header : `Content-Type : multipart/form-data`

Comment: working from postman and from laravel with Curl

Comment: oncee try  Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
     ])-

Comment: `dump($http->send('post', $endpoint, $httpParams)->body());die():` return `""`. But using postman or CURL this call return an xml

Comment: let me check with xml api once .searching for xml api .will let you know

Comment: $htppCall = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ])->get("https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A",[]);

    dd($htppCall->object());  it works fine but not sure about your case

Comment: Strange when I using : `Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])` I get `<Error message="This is NOT a multipart/form-data" code="110"/>` When I using `Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'])` I get `""`

Comment: yes so i cant guess whats going on  but errors says sent data is not multipart form data